# Cant Change Size of Image

Tags: html, css

I have a line under some menu button that i want to change the sixe of because when you view it on mobile the line goes further out than the menu. at this point even if i set the the size to 1px it doesnt change at all

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style= "background-color:white">
<!--<img  src ="/frontimages/orange_tab_wide_up.jpg" style= "display:inline-block">
<img  style="margin-left:-4px; display:inline-block" src ="/frontimages/blue_tab_wide.jpg">
<img style="margin-left:-4px; display:inline-block" src ="/frontimages/green_tab_wide.jpg">
<img style="margin-left:-4px; display:inline-block" src ="/frontimages/yellow_tab_wide.jpg">-->



<a class="btn-test btn" type="button" id="search" value="" onclick="check()" href="#" role="button">Search</a><a class="btn-test2 btn" type="button" id="search" value=""   onclick="check()" href="#" role="button">Search</a><a class="btn-test3 btn" type="button" id="search" value="" onclick="check()" href="#" role="button">Search</a><a class="btn-test4 btn" type="button" id="search" value="" onclick="check()" href="#" role="button">Search</a>

</div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
<div class ="col-xs-7 ">
<!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="/frontimages/orange_line_wide.png">-->
<div class="g"> </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .g {
    height:3px;
    margin-top:-3px;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%,#28ACEE 50%,#FFFFFF 100%); 
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%,#28ACEE 50%,#FFFFFF 100%); 
    background:linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%,#EC9B3F 50%,#FFFFFF 100%);
    width:100%;
    display:block;

    }

    @media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 350px) { 
    .g {width:1px;}
    }

    @media (max-width:700px) {
   .g{width: 405px}
    }
```

Comment: can you provide some snapshot or Fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Vxxb/ there's supposed to be a blue gradient line underneath the menu i don't know why it didn't show up. the line goes past the menu and i am trying to fix that issue so that it works correctly on mobile landscape view and portrait view

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to set `width:1px`?
Shouldn't `width:100%` work?

BTW, sometime if `width:100%` still out of bounds, I'll try `width: 99%`.

EDIT: change `width:100%` to `max-width:100%` will work!

Comment: I was just playing around with the size trying to see if it would change and I just forgot to change it back.

Comment: I tried setting the width to 100% it still didnt work. the line is still longer than the menu bar. whatever size i adjust the width to it does not change at all.

Comment: max-length should work but its not. on the PC it looks fine but when I view it on my responsive mobile the line comes out too far